# How to fix freeze_support() error for computing compute Perplexity and Coherence for LDA?

Tags: python, spyder, data-mining, lda, topic-modeling

I am going to compute Perplexity and Coherence for my textual data for LDA. I run the following codes

```
# Compute Perplexity
print('\nPerplexity: ', lda_model.log_perplexity(corpus))  # a measure of how good the model is. lower the better.
# Compute Coherence Score
coherence_model_lda = CoherenceModel(model=lda_model, texts=data_lemmatized, dictionary=id2word, coherence='c_v')
coherence_lda = coherence_model_lda.get_coherence()
print('\nCoherence Score: ', coherence_lda)
```

But I see this error (freeze_support()) I don't know how to fix it or even ignore it :

```
untimeError: 
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Compute Perplexity
print('\nPerplexity: ', lda_model.log_perplexity(corpus))  # a measure of how good the model is. lower the better.
# Compute Coherence Score
if __name__ ==  '__main__':
    coherence_model_lda = CoherenceModel(model=lda_model, texts=data_lemmatized, dictionary=id2word, coherence='c_v')
    coherence_lda = coherence_model_lda.get_coherence()
    print('\nCoherence Score: ', coherence_lda)
```